# How many maximum connections can oracle have?

Tags: oracle, max, connection

How many maximum number of connections can oracle handle ?

The following is a summary for my sql, i need similar stats for oracle :

The maximum number of connections MySQL can support depends on the quality of the thread library on a given platform, the amount of RAM available, how much RAM is used for each connection, the workload from each connection, and the desired response time. Linux or Solaris should be able to support at 500–1000 simultaneous connections routinely and as many as 10,000 connections if you have many gigabytes of RAM available and the workload from each is low or the response time target undemanding. Windows is limited to (open tables × 2 + open connections) < 2048 due to the Posix compatibility layer used on that platform.

Comment: What is an 'open table' and if it is open for 2 connections, does it count as 1 or as 2?

Answer (score 6):

Oracle has two types of connection architecture:

- In [**dedicated server**](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/process.htm#sthref1704) mode, each connection has a server process and you should have roughly the same limitations as in MySQL. This is the default connection mode and is recommended for small setup.
- In [**shared server**](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/process.htm#sthref1644) mode the connections will share the server processes:

> **Shared server** architecture eliminates
>   the need for a dedicated server
>   process for each connection. A
>   dispatcher directs multiple incoming
>   network session requests to a pool of
>   shared server processes. An idle
>   shared server process from a shared
>   pool of server processes picks up a
>   request from a common queue, which
>   means a small number of shared servers
>   can perform the same amount of
>   processing as many dedicated servers.
>   Also, because the amount of memory
>   required for each user is relatively
>   small, less memory and process
>   management are required, and **more
>   users can be supported**.

The jump from dedicated server to shared server architecture will be dictated by the number of connections and the workload. A mix of the two is possible (long running batch jobs in dedicated, front end web application in shared architecture).